# Flowchart of even and odd numbers

Tags: flowchart

I am struggling a little with a flowchart. The input is in a interval [k;j] and I need to get odd and even numbers sum separately.

Any tip is useful

Comment: A *lot* more information is needed here. How are you generating the flowchart? What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Take two sum variables, sumEven and sumOdd and initialize it with 0, then in the interval check if it is even or odd by dividing it by 2 and checking the remainder. If even, add it in sumEven otherwise in sumOdd. 
At last you'll have both the sums.